# IF THEN in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a DB in T-SQL and I have a problem now.

I have multiple rows with the same name but with a different value in one of the columns (in one row `doc` is 0 and in the second row `doc` is 2000), and some rows come just once and with only one value.

Now, I want to select all the ones where I have the 0 in the row, and if there is no 0 then I want to select the one with the value.

Here's sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([name] varchar(3), [doc] int, [sum] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([name], [doc], [sum])
VALUES
    ('tom', 0, 100),
    ('tom', 2000, 200),
    ('jon', 2000, 200)
;
```

Now I expect to get the row where TOM has the value of 100, and JON has the value of 200.

Comment: Instead of talking about rows i would show sample data and a desired result.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, first result from Google "tsql if then" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx

Comment: OK, the DB has 
name, doc, sum; 
tom, 0, 100; 
tom, 2000, 200;
jon, 2000, 200;

and now I expect to get the row where TOM has the value of 100, and JON has the value of 200.

My DB has about 500 000 rows, that is why I did not gave anything exactly. Sry

Comment: @tljubas please *edit* your question to add that information, nicely formatted! It doesn't really fit in a comment!

Answer (score 3):

One way, using [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT [name], 
                [doc], 
                [sum], 
                [rn] = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY name 
                         ORDER BY CASE WHEN doc=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
         FROM   table1) 
SELECT [name], 
       [doc], 
       [sum] 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14d7a/2/0) (with your sample data)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `A` column cannot have negative values:

```
select name, min(A)
from yourtable
group by name
```

If you want the entire row for each of the above, then you have to use a subquery:

```
select yourtable.* from yourtable
join (
    select name, min(A) [mina]
    from yourtable
    group by name
) a on a.name=yourtable.name and a.[mina]=yourtable.A
```

Answer (score 0):

This version uses a window function to count the number of rows with zero value for each name.  It then selects either the rows where the value is 0 or the rows with a valid value, using the logic in your question.

```
select name, value
from (select name, value,
             sum(case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as NumZeros
      from t
     ) t
 where numZeros = 0 or value = 0
```